# keeping all details of object removing the shape in the smoothest and most efficient way

Tags: python, image-processing, mask

I have some images for which I also have their mask (green in the picture). I am producing a bounding box (dot line in the picture) around the object, and take only this part of the image.

[image]

Now I would like to replace the gray part with pixel that extend the car color in the most natural way. For example, taking the same color as the closest car pixel. At the end I would like to have an image with all the car details but without any shape anymore.

I tried to simple inverse the mask, so that the mask represent the gray pixel around the car, and then use the 'inpaint' function from opencv to paint this new mask with adequate color:

```
result = cv2.inpaint(car_image,new_mask,50,cv2.INPAINT_NS)
```

Its not working well as we clearly still see the borders all around the car.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. I am working on python and it would need to be quite efficient as I have a huge number of images.

Comment: could anyone that have downvote this question explain the reason for this please?

Comment: There are probably some simple but inefficient ways to do it. Could you not extend the pixel colour from under the mask towards the edge? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to use inpainting methods, and can also think of non efficient way as computing a matrix of distance between each pixel and use it to find the closest non-black pixel.

Comment: The end result that you want is unclear. " without any shape anymore" ???

Comment: Yes, we should not see the shape of the care anymore, but keep all other information. This can be done by extending the border pixel for example, but I am not sure how would be the best way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good working solution, its a fucntion that given an image with zero value outside of the mask, it output a similar image where instead of the zero values the most adequate color is choosen so that we keep all details of the object but removing the form:

```
#replace black pixel by smoothing with adequate color to keep all info, removing shape 
def remove_shape_keep_all_info(img):
    #create mask (s.t. Non-zero pixels indicate the area that needs to be inpainted)
    mask_ = np.array([[1 if j==0 else 0 for j in i] for i in cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)]).astype('uint8')
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
    mask_ = cv2.dilate(mask_, kernel, iterations=4)
    result = cv2.inpaint(img,mask_,5,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA) #,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA, INPAINT_NS
    return (result)
```